# how can I save and load my bibliographic search in Scopus and Sciencedirect

Tags: bibliometrics, scopus, web-of-science

Can I save my bibliographic search in scientific databases, such as: Scopus or
Sciencedirect for loading my search later?

Comment: Why can't you just enter the same search parameters at a later time?

Comment: Googling for 'sciencedirect save search' brought up a number of places that tell you how to do it. I didn't try the same search on Scopus. On Web of Science one needs to have set up a personalized page, I presume the others are similar...

Answer (score 1):

A response regarding **Scopus** (you need to have an account for that):

Conduct your search and click on "Save" (just below the text which tells you the number of results).

[image: exemplary result page of a Scopus search query]

Your saved queries will be stored in the homepage of Scopus, under the query bar, next to "Search History":

[image: webpage of Scopus]